# Google Play Dev Console App Description

Tags: android, google-play

I noticed a developer's app's description had colour in it. I looked it up but can't find how to.. How do I add colour to an apps description in Google Play Developers Console so it shows up in Google Play.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aerobyn.stackoverflow - that's the app I noticed with a coloured description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app descriptions support a minimal number of HTML tags.
Looking at the page source I found

```
<font color="red">For all you having issues, <b>THERE WILL BE AN UPDATE SOON.</b></font>
```

So you can try to use the HTML `<font>` tag.